# Emmet - Can I write html so that the css structure will generate automatically?

Tags: html, css, emmet

I have one question.
I use Emmet to write html.
Can I write html so that the css structure will generate automatically?
For example... I write this code:

```
div.wrapper>div.head>a.logo+h1{Some text}
```

I will get this:

```
<div class="wrapper">
 <div class="head">
  <a href="" class="logo"></a>
  <h1>Some text</h1>
 </div>
</div>
```

I would like this result:

```
<div class="wrapper">
 <div class="head">
  <a href="" class="logo"></a>
  <h1>Some text</h1>
 </div>
</div>
<style>
   .wrapper {}
   .wrapper .head {}
   .wrapper .head a.logo {}
   .wrapper .head a:hover.logo {}
   .wrapper .head h1 {}
</style>
```

Is it possible?

Comment: what do you mean by "generate css structure automatically"?

Comment: i corrected my question. i hope you will understand what i mean

Comment: Using Emmet - the answer is no.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you checked out [primercss.](http://primercss.com/index.php) I think this is what you are asking for.

Comment: Yes! Exactly what I want. Thank you!